# How would I retrieve real-time sensory data and run it on a machine learning algorithm

Tags: python, spyder, live

I am currently using Spyder for this problem, I have reached to a point where I can harness the data from the sensors and a model could predict the accuracy based on my pre-recorded sessions.
I would like to know how would this trained model be used to predict incoming live data. My training dataset contains 7 columns in which 5(input) are sensory data and the remaining 2 are what the model would predict based on the input columns.
I have scoured the internet for any relatable example that would help my case, but haven't found anything useful yet, or maybe I have been searching the wrong keywords, any useful guidance would be appreciated.

I will attach a portion of my training data set so to better understand my problem.

[image: I will attach a portion of my training data set so to better understand my problem.]

Comment: How would you receive the live data, and how would it be used? I.e. do you think you'd have e.g. an HTTP or websocket endpoint that someone would talk to..? The concrete implementation depends a lot on that, but in the end if you already have a `model` you could call `.predict` on, then... you just plug some input data in there and do something with the output data.

Comment: (As an aside, "using Spyder" is somewhat irrelevant, since it's just the editor. Akin to "I'm using Word to write my novel, how do I make the characters interesting?")

Comment: What exactly do you want to predict? If you want the output columns (Gesture and Position) then just calling `model.predict` should work. If instead you want to predict future date for the input columns (Acx, Acy, AcZ...) then you would need to create a new model, something that looks at past data and tries to predict future one, in this case your current model wold be pretty useless

Comment: I have reached a point where I can harvest data from the sensors in real-time, put it neatly into columns and ready to be tested, the problem is that how do I make the model take a different data set for training and the live one for testing.

Comment: I have used the model.predict on the same data set but the data was not live, I think I would now have to use the that model for training and use the live data for testing, the problem is, I dont know how to....

Comment: Well, you aren't showing us any code, so it's pretty hard to help. But the idea is you save a trained model, then load it and predict on live data.

Comment: I have made it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to extract data, put it in a model, and it gave me answers in real-time, I will post the code below, plus a snippet of the variable explorer.

```
port = 'COM4'

baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()






oldline = []

while True:
    
   
        line = ser.readline()                 # read bytes until line-ending
        

        split_line = line.splitlines()

        if oldline != split_line:
            with open("live_data.csv","a") as f:
                for item in split_line:
                    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
                    print(writer.writerow([time.time(), item]))
          

        oldline = split_line
       

        
        colnames=['R'] 
        live_df=pd.read_csv("live_data.csv", names=colnames, header=None) #currently readng data
        
        live_df1=live_df['R'].str.split(',', expand=True)
        live_df4 = live_df1.rename({0:'AcX',1:'AcY',2:'AcZ',3:'FSR A',4:'FSR B'}, axis = 1)
        live_df.to_csv('live_data.csv')

        
        test_data_pre = live_df4
        
        
  
        test_data_pre1 = test_data_pre['AcX'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("b'", ""))
        test_data_pre2 = test_data_pre['FSR B'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'", ""))
        test_data_pre.drop(['AcX','FSR B'], inplace=True, axis=1)
        
        
        test_data_pre3 = pd.concat([test_data_pre1,test_data_pre],axis = 1)
        test_data_pre4 = pd.concat([test_data_pre3,test_data_pre2],axis = 1)
        test_data_pre4 = test_data_pre4.dropna(axis=0,how="any" )
        test_data_pre4 = test_data_pre4.apply(pd.to_numeric)
        



        test_data_pre4["Position"] = 0
        
        test_data_pre4["Gesture"] = 0
       
        live_df2=test_data_pre4
        

        


        test_data_pre4.loc[test_data_pre4["FSR B"] > 1000 ,'Gesture'] = 1
        test_data_pre4.loc[test_data_pre4["FSR A"] > 1700 ,'Gesture'] = 1
        test_data_pre4[test_data_pre4['Gesture']==1]
        
        test_data_pre4.to_csv('live_finalized.csv')
        
        live_df3=test_data_pre4.copy()
        
        train_data=pd.read_csv("Trained_Data.csv")
        train_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace = True)
        
        live_df3 = live_df3.fillna(method = 'bfill')

        X = train_data[['AcX','AcY','AcZ']]
        y = train_data['Position']

        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8, random_state=55, shuffle=True, stratify=y)


        from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
        
        X_test = test_data_pre4[['AcX','AcY','AcZ']]
        y_test = test_data_pre4['Position']
        model = LDA ()
        model.fit(X, y)
        predicted_types = model.predict(X_test)
        
        print(predicted_types)

        from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

        accuracy_score(y_test,predicted_types)
        
        
        
        print(".................Predictions Only................")
        print(predicted_types)
        print(".................Predictions with the rest of dataset................")
       
        test5=test_data_pre4.copy()
        df = pd.DataFrame(test5,columns= [test_data_pre4['AcX'],test_data_pre4['AcY'],test_data_pre4['AcZ'],predicted_types])
        df_t=df.transpose()
      
        gg=(df_t.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3]])
        gg = gg.dropna(axis=1,how="any" )
        print(gg)
```

There are 5 inputs = 'AcX' 'AcY' 'AcZ' , 'FSR A'  'FSR B'

Two outputs are manipulated based off of these inputs, The Position is as you guessed is based on the X,Y,Z values and the gesture is controlled by the 'FSR A' and 'B'
I have used a threshold value on the FSR values (since the output was simple), while for the position I have used a pre-trained dataset.
Keep in mind, this is all done in real-time.

The  index column in the snippet displays the respective predicted position according to the X, Y, Z values

[image]

The snippet below shows the respective gesture variable according to the FSR A and B values, notice how the gesture value changes from 0 to 1 as it goes above the threshold. (ignore the position column, it is not relevant).

[image]